# PHP Page-Specific Scripts and Styles Not Recognized

Tags: php, variables, include

I have a site built with PHP includes. For scripts and styles that are used on only one page, I call them with a variable. So the header include contains this line:

```
<?php echo $additional; ?>
```

And a particular page that requires additional scripts and styles contains these lines:

```
<?php $additional = '<link href="/assets/style_tabbedpanels_calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link href="/assets/style_calendar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script src="/assets/script_tabbedpanels_t-l.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/assets/script_calendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/assets/script_yahoo-dom-event.js" type="text/javascript"></script>'; ?>
```

I didn't break each style and script onto a new line because I found that causes problems. Generally, this has worked fine, but the calendar and yahoo-dom-event scripts that I just added aren't running at all. I know this because everything works if I put them directly in the header include.

So I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong when defining the additional variable on the individual pages?

Thank you.

Comment: view source, is there any variation in the actully generated html between the two approaches?

Comment: The HTML is generated the same. The only difference is line breaks (whatever is immediately after the additional placeholder in the header include isn't on a new line).

Answer (score 1):

The problem seemed to be the order of the scripts. When I moved the yahoo one in front of the others, it started working.